# advice for curve fitting

Tags: elliptic-curves, plane-curves, curves, elliptic-functions

I have numerically obtained some curves, corresponding with it I have also obtained some roots. I strongly believed these curves can be fitted with some (elliptic) functions taken the roots as parameters. However, due to the limitation of my mathematical knowledge, I haven't fount a very nice fit. So here I am asking for advice based on your experience with the graph of the functions.

ps:The most relevant graph I found up to now is the second [EllipticTheta](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticTheta.html?q=EllipticTheta) function. However, I don't figure out how I can apply the roots as good parameters.

---

roots: $\pm0.000924287 \pm 0.00336612 I$
[image]

---

roots:$\pm0.00120276 \pm 0.00332996 I$

[image]

---

roots:$\pm0.00142757 \pm 0.00329385 I$
[image]

---

roots:$\pm0.0016212 \pm 0.00325777 I1$
[image]

---

roots:$\pm0.00179376 \pm 0.00322174 I$
[image]

---

roots:$\pm0.00195085 \pm0.00318575 I$
[image]

Comment: Well, you can easily map the amplitude, and the period with ellipticTheta(x/T).  ( But your roots are 2 floats, so its undercontrained for a fitting  )    . Then for one root I will plot the difference between your curve and ellipticTheta(2,x/T,a) to get the best a, then to try to infer a fit.
Anyway note that something special occurs in 0.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET The frequency seems to mismatch the roots. Also, can you tell me how can I read the amplitude from the graph? it seems that the amplitude(on the graph) depends also on the last parameter of the EllipticTheta.

Comment: amplitude seems constant ~= 0.007 to me. or not ?  "Freq seems to mismatch the root": well, there are so many possibilities to make 1 float from 2 floats...

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET they are decreasing... but slowly... the hight is about 0.00669, 0.006642,0.006548.......